# funcaptcha callback on signin.ea.com

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I've problem with callback  token funcaptcha on singin.ea.com.

```
"postMessage(JSON.stringify({eventId:'challenge-complete',payload:{sessionToken:'" + code + "'}}),'*')"
```

or

```
              var anyCaptchaToken = '"""+code+"""';
              var enc = document.querySelector("[data-e2e=enforcement-frame]");
              var encWin = enc.contentWindow || enc;
              var encDoc = enc.contentDocument || encWin.document;
              let script = encDoc.createElement('SCRIPT');
              script.append('function AnyCaptchaSubmit(token) { parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ eventId: "challenge-complete", payload: { sessionToken: token } }), "*") }');
              encDoc.documentElement.appendChild(script);
              encWin.AnyCaptchaSubmit(anyCaptchaToken);
```

and change value of hidden inputs `verification-token` and `FunCaptcha-Token`

no effects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.